# Servlet API - Filter Response Wrapper

Tags: java, servlets, filter, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I am new to Servlet programming and I have a question about wrapping response. Because I couldnt understand when to use it. For example I have filter and servlet as below.

**Filter**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)resp;
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().println("hi from filter");
    }
```

**Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        response.getWriter().println("Hi from servlet");
    }
```

So , What is the difference between them ? I could use both of them to write by using same response object because there are full duplex way (Sincerely, same request and response instances goes to servlet and comes to filter again) between servlet and filter , aren't there ? I am little confused. I appriciate If you could give me a decent sceneraio that could obviously demonstrate the wrapper class's goal. 
Thanks & Regards :)

Comment: What if you don't want to append something to the response, but transform what the servlet sent (like adding things in the middle, or replace pieces by other pieces, or compress)?

Comment: actually that's not wrapping or decorating, that's just casting...